# How to jump to hrefs of h2 for specific pages per JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, href, scrolltop, menubar

This is working (example is the id of an h2-Tag.):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
jQuery(document).ready(function($){
    var menubarHeight = 54;
    $('a[href^=#]').on('click', function(e){
        var href = $(this).attr('href');
        $('html, body').animate({
            scrollTop:$(href).offset().top -menubarHeight }, 1);
    });
});
```

```
<script type="text/javascript">
jQuery(document).ready(function($){
    var menubarHeight = 154;
    $('a[href^=#idofh2]').on('click', function(e){
        var href = $(this).attr('href');
        $('html, body').animate({
            scrollTop:$(href).offset().top -menubarHeight }, 1);
    });
});
```

This is not working (I want this function for all hrefs of h2 only for this pages -> https://example.com/, https://example.com/2.):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
jQuery(document).ready(function($){
    var menubarHeight = 154;
    $('a[href^=#]').on('click', function(e){
        // Here you can see, that there is h2. I don't know where to place it.
        var href = $(this).attr('h2');
        $('html, body').animate({
            scrollTop:$(href).offset().top -menubarHeight }, 1);
    });
});
```

I am using 1, because I want to jump and no smooth scrolling. What can I use instead of .animate?

If I use this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
jQuery(document).ready(function($){
    var menubarHeight = 54;
    $('a[href^=#]').on('click', function(e){
        var href = $(this).attr('href');
        $('html, body').css("scrollTop", $(href).offset().top -menubarHeight);
    });
});
```

then 54 dosen't works.

This:

```
$('a[href^=#]')
```

is generally for 54.

And this:

```
$('a[href^=#idofh2]')
```

is an id of one h2 tag of a page. That works. But how can I use it for all h2 tags and only for the pages https://example.com/, https://example.com/2? If I jump to an h2 tag, it has to be 154 (menubarHeight) otherwise 54.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on your question, I guess what you want to do is to set the `menuHeight` to either 154 or 54, depending if the target of the `href` points to a `<h2>` element or not. This is when jQuery's [`.is()`](http://api.jquery.com/is/) method comes into handy.

So, you can simply use the `.is('h2')` method to check if the selected node's tagname matches `h2`:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($){
    $('a[href^=#]').on('click', function(e){
        var href = $(this).attr('href');

        // Store the target element reference
        var $target = $(href);

        // Check if target element is a <h2> element
        var isTargetH2 = $target.is('h2');

        // Use ternary operators to set menuHeight
        // - If target element is <h2>, use 154
        // - Otherwise, use 54
        var menubarHeight = isTargetH2 ? 154 : 54;

        $('html, body').css("scrollTop", $target.offset().top - menubarHeight);
    });
});
```

Comment: Thanks. It works but I realized, that the id is inside a span tag of h2. How can I select it? In CSS there is a code: `@media (min-width: ?px){}`. How can I use it in JavaScript and also only for the URLs https://example.com/, https://example.com/2 to be more specific?

Comment: @user8652270 If the span with ID is a direct child of h2 you can simply check `$target.parent().is('h2')`. For that to work on specific URLs you will need to check `window.location.href`.

Comment: That works, but only, if the page is loaded. Then I can click. The problem is, that the Website (for example: http://example.com/#idofh2) not use my JavaScript, if I open it directly in Chrome (Google Web Search or address bar). I use WordPress. Cause of that it shows me the jump of WordPress to the id. I can see the jump also, if the page is loaded. After the jump of WordPress comes the jump of my js code and by opening from the address bar directly it shows me only the jump of WordPress so that headings are covered by the menu bar.

Comment: @user8652270 Then you need to use JS to detect the hash of the URL when your page is loaded so that it adjusts the scroll position properly. That’s different from binding the clock handler to your anchor element. But the inner logic remains the same.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to just jump to a dom with an id, you can call it as a link

```
<a href="#idOfTheDom">Jump</a>
```

This doesn't causes the side to be reloaded.

*If I understood the question incorrectly, please provide more informations.*

```html
<a href="#1">Jump</a>
<div style="height:500px"></div>
<h2 id="1">This is the H2</h2>
<div style="height:500px"></div>
```

Comment: I think the reason why OP is not using the native browser functionality is because he likely has a fix positioned menu bar on the top of the page, which will obscure the content. That's why his code contains the logic of detecting the height of the said menu bar.

Answer (score 0):

First, if you just need change scrollTop you can use "css" method instead of animate:

```
.css({
        scrollTop:$(href).offset().top -menubarHeight
});
```

or

```
.css("scrollTop", $(href).offset().top -menubarHeight);
```

I don't get your question well! Do you want to scroll on titles (h2 tags) by link?